# Rails ar_mailer fails to send emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, smtp, ar-mailer

I've just switched an application to use ar_mailer and when I run ar_sendmail (after a long pause) I get the following error:

```
Unhandled exception 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. h7sm16260325nfh.4
```

I am using Gmail SMTP to send the emails and I haven't changed any of the ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings just installed ar_mailer.

Versions:

Rails: 2.1, ar_mailer: 1.3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did some digging in the lib and it seems that if you want to use TLS (as you do with Gmail) then it adds a new option to the ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings of :tls (default of which is false) which you should set to true.

The only thing the installation instructions mention regarding TLS is to remove any other smtp_tls files, but the one I had didn't require the tls option to work.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you use the Ruby version 1.8.7

You don't need the `smtp_tls` before.

You just need add the `enable_startls_auto` option:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :enable_starttls_auto => true,
  ...
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of ar_mailer are you using? A gmail specific bug was fixed in 1.3.1, as shown here:

http://rubyforge.org/forum/forum.php?forum_id=16364